# CSS - min and max prefixes question

Tags: css

What exactly are the min and max prefixes in CSS? And are there any docs that explain them in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about `min-width` and `max-width` (`-height`), they are not "prefixed". There are simply rules that are called `min-width` and `max-width` and also a rule that's called `width`. These are completely different rules that do different (albeit similar) things.

Perhaps see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference.

Comment: I want to know more about the min and max prefixes

Comment: @CNUT They are **not** prefixes. You want to know more about the *rules* `min-width` and `max-width`. Read the documentation I and @a3_nm linked to.

Comment: I never said anything about the height or width

Comment: @CNUT Then please give an example of what you *are* talking about in context, because there's no such thing as a "min prefix" in CSS and we're apparently talking about different things.

Comment: but reading thru the docs you recommended gave me an idea of what min and max are.

Comment: Be careful when using mix- and max- because Internet Explorer sometimes misinterprets your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

For min-width, max-width, min-height and max-height, you can find details in the CSS 2.1 specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths (description for height is a bit further down).

You might be interested by the algorithm description ("The following algorithm describes how the two properties influence the used value of the 'width' property:"). Basically, what seems to be going on is that a tentative width is computed ignoring the min-width and max-width properties. If it is larger than max-width, computation takes place again as if a width value of max-width had been specified. If the result is smaller than min-width, same thing with a width value equal to that of min-wdith.